# Dirty cow kernel patch for kernel version 3.3.8

Tags: linux-kernel

I have an older version of kernel i.e 3.3.8 so I need a patch to secure it from dirty cow bug.Please give any solution or direction.

Comment: [Might help](https://www.google.de/search?q=How+To+Protect+Your+server+Against+Dirty+Cow&safe=active&gws_rd=cr&ei=g-M3WOHVEoLrUuWugeAN)... Hard to find; I know but with a teeny tiny bit of effort still possible. Please research before asking!

Comment: I have no experience working with kernel sources, and don't know much about how mm module works. Which is the reason I might have been looking in the wrong places in the kernel source for gup.c and other related files. Appreciate your help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the patch and patch it up.

Here is the link to download it as the patch [patch file](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/patch/?id=19be0eaffa3ac7d8eb6784ad9bdbc7d67ed8e619)

Assuming you downloaded the patch file and copied in the source directory of you linux (3.8.8).
    Now just use the patch command to patch it up.

```
patch -p1 < name_of_the_patch_file_downloaded.patch
```

Answer (score 2):

take below commit from "v4.9-rc2" & back port to your kernel;

19be0ea mm: remove gup_flags FOLL_WRITE games from __get_user_pages()